# How to hide the button when array reaches the length in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to limit the items to 4 each time. Once all the items gets displayed, i want to get the index of the last item from outside ngFor loop to hide the button.

```js
this.limit = 4;
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
  <template [ngIf]="i<limit">{{item}}   
   </template>
</ng-container>

<div *ngIf="">
  <button (click)="limit=limit+4">Show More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: *How to hide the button when array reaches the length in angular2*? Isn't it just `<div *ngIf="items.length < limit">`?

Comment: it could be better you handle this functionality in .ts rather than template

Answer (score 0):

> How to hide the button when array reaches the length in angular2?

Isn't it just check if the `array` *length* is less than `limit`?

```
<ng-container *ngIf="items.length < limit">
  <button (click)="limit=limit+4">Show More</button>
</ng-container>
```